# How to animate geom_path plots with gganimate in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, gif, gganimate

I am trying to make a smooth animation of lines that move over time.  Here is some example data **edited to add `x` for completeness as I forgot that initially, apologies**:

```
x <- c( 0, 10, 19, 27, 35, 41, 48, 52, 55, 56 )
test.data <- data.frame( depth  = rep( seq( 1, 10 ), 10 ), 
                         time = rep( 1:10, times = 1, each = 10 ),
                         temp = rep( x, 10 ) + rep( 0:9, each = length( x ) ) )
```

Now arrange the data so that `geom_path` links the data correctly

```
 arrange( test.data, depth, time )  ## arrange by depth for plotting
```

Now make the static plot with all the data shown:

```
ggplot( test.data, aes( x = temp, y = depth, group = time ) ) +
        ylim( 10, 0 ) +
        labs( y = "Depth (km)", 
              x = "Temp (C)",
              color = "Time") +
        geom_path( aes( color = time ) )
```

Here is the static plot:
[image]

Now do the animation using `gganimate`

```
library(gganimate)

plot.for.gif <- test.data %>% 
   ggplot( aes( x = temp, y = depth, group = time ) ) +
   ylim( 10, 0 ) +
   labs( y = "Depth (km)", 
         x = "Temp (C)",
         color = "Time (Ma)") +
   geom_path( aes( color = time ) )

plot.animation = plot.for.gif +
   transition_time( time = time ) +
   labs( subtitle = "Time (Ma): {frame_time}" ) +
   shadow_mark( past = TRUE, future = FALSE, exclude_layer = NULL )

   animate( plot.animation, height = 1400, width = 800, fps = 10, duration = 15, res = 150 )
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image]

The problem is that the lines do not blend into one another, they jump from one frame to another. I'd like to get them to move smoothly between discrete frames.

I've tried playing with `shadow_wake()` and `enter_fade()` but neither work. It seems like `gganimate()` doesn't smooth lines connecting datapoints well, but I am perhaps missing an easy fix.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Edited to be fully replicable - added the `x` determination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide `x` in your question, but presuming it's something like this:

```r
x <- seq(0, 9)^(2/3) * 15
```

Then we can do:

```r
test.data <- data.frame( depth  = rep( seq( 1, 10 ), 10 ), 
                         time = rep( 1:10, times = 1, each = 10 ),
                         temp = rep(x, 10 ) + rep( 0:9, each = length( x ) ) )

library(gganimate)

plot.for.gif <- test.data %>% 
  mutate(time = factor(time)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = temp, y = depth, color = as.numeric(time)) ) +
  geom_path() +
  labs(color = "time") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  transition_states(time, transition_length = 1, state_length = 0.1) 

animate(plot.for.gif, fps = 30, duration = 3, detail = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan!  the issue is that I was using a `group` variable in the original `aes()` call I guess.  Quick question - why the code converting `time` to a factor and then back to numeric?   Also, quick note - I think the `animate( plot.animation...` should be `animate(plot.for.gif...` in your answer?

Comment: @Jesse I was making sure that time was treated as a factor within transition_states (may not be necessary). Obviously it had to be changed back to preserve the continuous color scale when mapping to colour. You are right about the last point - now corrected - thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to leave `shadow_mark(past = TRUE,...)` out. This keeps the lines from the past in the animation.

I have created an own DF which comes close to yours. (I couldn't  figure out, how your variable `temp` was created.)

If you then leave `group = time` out you get a smooth animation.

```
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)

depth  = rep( seq( 1, 10 ), 10 )
time = rep( 1:10, times = 1, each = 10 )
temp = depth + time

test.data <- data.frame(depth, time)
arrange( test.data, depth, time ) 

anim <- ggplot( test.data, aes( x = temp, y = depth)) +
  ylim( 10, 0 ) +
  labs( y = "Depth (km)", 
        x = "Temp (C)",
        color = "Time") +
  geom_path( aes( color = time ) ) +
  transition_time(time) 
  #shadow_mark(past = T) # leave this out

animate(anim)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MarBlo, just a quick followup - the problem does not seem to be the `shadow_mark( past = T)` call. That works just fine. However, the `group` determination does seem to be the problem. Thanks for pointing that out!